# running auditd in docker container

Tags: linux, docker, centos

I am trying to configure the rsyslog client in centos docker container and i noticed below error. looks like rsyslogd is exiting due to the auditd failure.

Any idea how to make rsyslog service to work inside the centos docker container?

Tried this [suggestion](https://serverfault.com/questions/824975/systemctl-failed-to-get-d-bus-connection-operation-not-permitted) but no luck.

```
May 16 09:49:35 ad5de951dcd4 auditd[312]: Started dispatcher: /sbin/audispd pid: 316
May 16 09:49:35 ad5de951dcd4 auditd[312]: Unable to set initial audit startup state to 'enable', exiting
May 16 09:49:35 ad5de951dcd4 auditd[312]: The audit daemon is exiting.
May 16 09:49:35 ad5de951dcd4 systemd: auditd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 16 09:49:35 ad5de951dcd4 audispd: syslog plugin initialized
May 16 09:49:35 ad5de951dcd4 audispd: audispd initialized with q_depth=150 and 1 active plugins
May 16 09:49:35 ad5de951dcd4 augenrules: /sbin/augenrules: No change
May 16 09:49:35 ad5de951dcd4 auditctl: The audit system is disabled
May 16 09:49:35 ad5de951dcd4 systemd: Failed to start Security Auditing Service.
May 16 09:49:35 ad5de951dcd4 systemd: Unit auditd.service entered failed state.
May 16 09:49:35 ad5de951dcd4 systemd: auditd.service failed.
May 16 09:49:53 ad5de951dcd4 systemd: Starting Security Auditing Service...
May 16 09:49:53 ad5de951dcd4 auditd[330]: Started dispatcher: /sbin/audispd pid: 333
May 16 09:49:53 ad5de951dcd4 auditd[330]: Unable to set initial audit startup state to 'enable', exiting
May 16 09:49:53 ad5de951dcd4 auditd[330]: The audit daemon is exiting.
May 16 09:49:53 ad5de951dcd4 systemd: auditd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 16 09:49:53 ad5de951dcd4 audispd: syslog plugin initialized
May 16 09:49:53 ad5de951dcd4 audispd: audispd initialized with q_depth=150 and 1 active plugins
May 16 09:49:53 ad5de951dcd4 augenrules: /sbin/augenrules: No change
May 16 09:49:53 ad5de951dcd4 auditctl: The audit system is disabled
May 16 09:49:53 ad5de951dcd4 systemd: Failed to start Security Auditing Service.
May 16 09:49:53 ad5de951dcd4 systemd: Unit auditd.service entered failed state.
May 16 09:49:53 ad5de951dcd4 systemd: auditd.service failed.
May 16 10:09:57 ad5de951dcd4 systemd: Reloading.
May 16 10:10:02 ad5de951dcd4 systemd: Reloading.
May 16 10:10:10 ad5de951dcd4 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.7" x-pid="421" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 2.
```

Comment: Add your Dockerfile to your question.

Comment: I am using base centos container and inside that container installed few services using below commands
`yum install rsyslog rsyslog-doc
yum install rsyslog-gnutls
yum -y install audit
yum -y install initscripts `

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this doesn't directly solve the rsyslog issue, but will give you a route of investigation.

auditd doesn't work in docker currently (I ran into similar issues), see this thread:
https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2016-February/msg00011.html

So if auditd isn't crucial to your usage you should find a way to disable that in rsyslog.